# Using ReactDom.render() and jQuery() javascript in the same document (Solve)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, render, react-dom

I'm making a website where first I use the JSX and React to creat the content and later wanna use the jQuery to create a slideshow, but I don know why the slideshow doesnt work.

```
function Peli (prop){JSX code}
$(document).ready(function)(){slideshow})
let element = <Peli />
ReactDOM.render((element), document.getElementById('root'))
```

If the code for the slideshow is put in the html file works

In either of the cases the console doesn't show an error

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean? are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: The slideshow code doesnt work if is put in the same file of the render file,

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

> React elements are immutable. Once you create an element, you can’t
>   change its children or attributes.